# How to binarize gray ROI by keeping red background same?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale image plus a red background:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue7nq.jpg

In next step of image processing I want to binarize only the gray region of interest while keeping the red background as it is. But when I apply im2bw all of the image is converted to black and white, including the red background. How can I keep the red background as it is and convert the gray ROI  to binary?

Comment: would you put the figure please?

Comment: 1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ue7nq.jpg

Comment: could you put your code , how you get the ROI ?
im2BW does not give you colors, because it's logical type :(0 or 1)

Comment: Yes im2bw does not give color image. But I want to make that gray ROI from image 1st to binary and I need to calculate the ratio of that black and white pixels.

Comment: @user1984451, please post a link to the pure image that should be processed. ue7nq.jpg is good for illustration, but not to try out possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but here are a few things (if you have the Image Processing Toolbox):

Create a mask out of the red in your leftmost image like this:

```
BWRGB=cat(3, im2bw(crp(:,:,1)), im2bw(crp(:,:,2)),im2bw(crp(:,:,3)));
BW2=BWRGB(:,:,1)&(~BWRGB(:,:,2)&~BWRGB(:,:,3));
imshow(BW2);
```

[image: mask]

Then populate the 3 layers of the RGB image using the mask:

```
BW3=im2bw(YourImage);
BW3(:,:,1)=BW3(:,:,1).*BW2+(255*double(~BW2));
BW3(:,:,2)=BW3(:,:,1).*BW2; 
BW3(:,:,3)=BW3(:,:,1).*BW2;

imshow(im2uint8(BW3));
```

Result:

[image]